# How to get GL_VIEWPORT dimensions in Android GL10?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'd like to accomplish the following in Android using API Level 7:

```
glGet(GL_VIEWPORT, someBuffer)
```

[Documentation for OpenGL ES 1.1](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glGet.xml) shows this as part of the C API.

I've tried using the following code:

```
    int[] results = new int[4];
    gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS, results, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        Log.e(TAG, "results[" + i + "]: " + results[i]);
    }
```

I get output in various phases of the surface like so:

```
onSurfaceCreated called
    results[0]: 4096
    results[1]: 4096
    results[2]: 0
    results[3]: 0
onSurfaceChanged called with height: 800 and width: 480
  //NOTE: gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); is called here
    results[0]: 4096
    results[1]: 4096
    results[2]: 0
    results[3]: 0
onDrawFrame called
    results[0]: 4096
    results[1]: 4096
    results[2]: 0
    results[3]: 0
```

How would one do this using Android's kronos GLES?

Comment: Do you want to get maximum possible size of viewport (GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS) or current size of viewport (GL_VIEWPORT) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that Android protects you from yourself. `onSurfaceChanged` is called before any `onDrawFrame` calls. It's on us to capture and persist any of this data.

Answer (score 0):

The constant `GL_VIEWPORT` is not part of interface [`GL10`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html), but of [`GL11`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL11.html). Try using `GL11.GL_VIEWPORT` instead. If you think this does not befit, you can cast the instance to `GL11` before, but this does not make any difference.

Comment: `GL11` didn't work. It still returned all zeros. I tried a larger buffer as well.

Comment: Did you get any error (`glGetError`)? Did you call the method _after_ `onSurfaceChanged`? Is there a valid GL context?